# Distinguish between IPv4 and IPV6 regexp - match for : sufficient?

Tags: regex, ipv6, ipv4

I had sub-routine which needs to do 2 different actions based on whether the address is IPV4 or IPV6. If I just pattern match for ':' to determine whether the address is IPV6 ?

Are there any exceptions ?

Eg: 1.1.1.1 has no colon
    1::1 has :

Also will the above work for subnets :
Eg : 1.2.3.4/24 
     2002::1.2.3.4/120

I do not want to use the huge regexp pattern match for either IPV4 or IPV6.
Thanks.

Comment: What about `120.0.0.1:8000`?

Comment: Matching for dots feels safer

Comment: @JanDvorak If you match an url that would be correct. Not for IP addresses though.

Comment: @JanDvorak, ::FFFF:192.168.1.1 is a valid IPv6 address.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a full IPV6 match, then there is a complete regex
[here](http://vernon.mauery.com/content/projects/linux/ipv6_regex):

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Did you forget to actually quote the reference?

Comment: @Jan, the regex which was used, was too big, hence I just added the link. Will make sure to quote from next time.

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell, if count of colons in input >=2, consider it IPv6.

---

I had the same problem where the input can be either IPv4 or IPv6 or host name and optionally a port in each case. Based on the input, it was required to be validated with the appropriate regex.

The approach I considered was to **count the number of colons** in the input. If `colonCount >= 2` => IPv6, otherwise either an IPv4 or host name. IPv6 was later extracted based on presence of port if it exists between `[` and `]:`. For v4/host, just split with `:`. Remaining string is a pure IP address (v4/v6) or host name which could be evaluated with appropriate regex.